# why this setAttribute function not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, getelementbyid, setattribute

i want my para with id "fn_warn" to be visible when submit is clicked.

my html and js code is as,

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    First name
    <input id="first_name" type="text"/>
    <p id="fn_warn" style=" visibility: hidden; color: red;">#Please enter a valid name...</p>
    <input class="button" onclick="tada();" type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input class="button" type="reset" />
</body>
</html>

<script>
    function tada(){
       var x= document.getElementById("fn_warn");
       x.setAttribute("visibility","visible");
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: It probably is. Are you intending to make the element visible?

Comment: I think you want element.style.visibility = "visible"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS rules are not attributes. Use the `style` property instead since the rule is inline:

```
function tada(){
    var x = document.getElementById("fn_warn");
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```